# Заполнение пропущенных значений для модели машинного обучения

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, обработка-данных, nan

Нужно заполнить пропущенные значения для модели машинного обучения.

С помощью функции `calculate_means` (oна заранее написана в задании):

```
def calculate_means(numeric_data):
means = np.zeros(numeric_data.shape[1])
for j in range(numeric_data.shape[1]):
    to_sum = numeric_data.iloc[:,j]
    indices = np.nonzero(~numeric_data.iloc[:,j].isnull())[0]
    correction = np.amax(to_sum[indices])
    to_sum /= correction
    for i in indices:
        means[j] += to_sum[i]
    means[j] /= indices.size
    means[j] *= correction
return pd.Series(means, numeric_data.columns)


data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

X = data.drop('Grant.Status', 1)
y = data['Grant.Status']

numeric_cols = ['RFCD.Percentage.1', 'RFCD.Percentage.2', 'RFCD.Percentage.3', 
            'RFCD.Percentage.4', 'RFCD.Percentage.5',
            'SEO.Percentage.1', 'SEO.Percentage.2', 'SEO.Percentage.3',
            'SEO.Percentage.4', 'SEO.Percentage.5',
            'Year.of.Birth.1', 'Number.of.Successful.Grant.1', 'Number.of.Unsuccessful.Grant.1']
categorical_cols = list(set(X.columns.values.tolist()) - set(numeric_cols))

means = calculate_means(X[numeric_cols])
X_real_mean = X[numeric_cols]
for i in range(len(numeric_cols)):
    X_real_mean.iloc[:, i] = X_real_mean.iloc[:, i].fillna(means.values[i])
```

Но не могу понять, что делать с этой ошибкой:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-7d79cc69311f> in <module>
  2 X_real_zeros = X[numeric_cols].fillna(0)
  3 
 ----> 4 means = calculate_means(X[numeric_cols])
  5 X_real_mean = X[numeric_cols]
  6 for i in range(len(numeric_cols)):

 <ipython-input-8-a1d3e6085deb> in calculate_means(numeric_data)
  3     for j in range(numeric_data.shape[1]):
  4         to_sum = numeric_data.iloc[:,j]
  ----> 5         indices = np.nonzero(~numeric_data.iloc[:,j].isnull())[0]
  6         correction = np.amax(to_sum[indices])
  7         to_sum /= correction

 <__array_function__ internals> in nonzero(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in nonzero(a)
1906 
1907     """
-> 1908     return _wrapfunc(a, 'nonzero')
 1909 
1910 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
 53     bound = getattr(obj, method, None)
 54     if bound is None:
 ---> 55         return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
 56 
 57     try:

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
 46         if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):
 47             result = asarray(result)
 ---> 48         result = wrap(result)
 49     return result
 50 

   ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __array_wrap__(self, result, context)
 1788             return result
 1789         d = self._construct_axes_dict(self._AXIS_ORDERS, copy=False)
-> 1790         return self._constructor(result, **d).__finalize__(
 1791             self, method="__array_wrap__"
  1792         )

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, 
copy, fastpath)
311                 try:
312                     if len(index) != len(data):
 --> 313                         raise ValueError(
314                             f"Length of passed values is {len(data)}, "
315                             f"index implies {len(index)}."

 ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies 6000.
```

Comment: Навскидку непонятно. Попробуйте напечатать, что у вас  `~numeric_data.iloc[:,j].isnull()` выдаёт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если добавить в той строке на которую ругается `.values`, то перестаёт ругаться и вроде работает:

```
indices = np.nonzero(~numeric_data.iloc[:,j].isnull().values)[0]
                                                     ^^^^^^^
```

Природу сего явления объяснить не могу, видимо, какое-то недопонимание между данными `Pandas.Series` и функцией `Numpy`.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо монстрообразной и медленной (невекторизированной) функции `calculate_means()`, которая к тому же молча изменяет данные в переданном ей фрейме, можно воспользоваться простым векторизированным решением:

```
In [148]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2 ,np.nan], "b":[1,2,3]})

In [149]: df
Out[149]:
     a  b
0  1.0  1
1  2.0  2
2  NaN  3

In [150]: means = df.apply(lambda col: col.dropna().mean())

In [151]: means
Out[151]:
a    1.5
b    2.0
dtype: float64
```

---

Демонстрация того, как исправленная функция `calculate_means()` меняет значения переданного ей фрейма:

```
In [152]: df
Out[152]:
     a  b
0  1.0  1
1  2.0  2
2  NaN  3

In [153]: calculate_means(df)
Out[153]:
a    1.5
b    2.0
dtype: float64

In [154]: df
Out[154]:
     a  b
0  0.5  1
1  1.0  2
2  NaN  3
```

обратите внимание на изменившиеся значения в столбце `a`!